# How to fix my DB model to remedy unique violations?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, many-to-many

I know that primary key values cannot be repeated. However, I want to make it so that games can be played on more than one platform. For example "Dark Souls" on PC and PS4. How do I modify the relational design so that I can give a `SpelID` multiple consoles without repeating it?
This is my code:

```
drop table if exists Spel;
drop table if exists Plattform;
drop table if exists Företag;

create table Företag (
    FöretagID varchar(50) primary key,
    Företag text,
    Högk text
);

create table Plattform (
    PlattformID integer primary key,
    Plattform varchar (50)
);

create table Spel (
    SpelID integer primary key,
    namn varchar(50),
    genre text,
    år date,
    Åldergräns char(2),
   
    foreign key (SpelID) references Plattform (PlattformID),
    foreign key (namn) references Företag (FöretagID)
);

insert into Företag (FöretagID, Företag, Högk)
    values ('Zelda', 'Capcom', 'Japan'),
           ('Bloodborne', 'From', 'Japan');
        

insert into Plattform (PlattformID, Plattform)
    values (0001, 'Nintendo'),
           (0001, 'PS4'),
           (0002, 'PS4'),
           (0002, 'Nintendo');


insert into Spel (SpelID, namn, genre, år, Åldergräns)
    values (0001, 'Zelda', 'Äventyr', '2015-10-12', 7),
           (0002, 'Bloodborne', 'A-RPG', '2017-09-09', 18);
```

I have tried to add them in the `Plattform` table but I know that a primary key can only have one specific value. (Spel = Game)

Comment: Your current code already throws  errors (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/V4h9-Obt) ,and you are not sharing what your actually tried... (and why that failed)

Comment: If I remove (0001, 'PS4') and (0002, 'Nintendo') then I don't get errors but they appear when they are added within the "Plattform " table. This is what I am trying to fix,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [many-to-many relationship in database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273715/many-to-many-relationship-in-database-design)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to drop the current CONSTRAINT:

```
-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075413/change-primary-key-in-postgresql-table
-- DROP THE Primary key
-- ALTER TABLE plattform DROP CONSTRAINT  plattform_pkey ;

-- not possible because of some forein keys, so drop other keys tooo:
ALTER TABLE plattform DROP CONSTRAINT  plattform_pkey CASCADE;
```

Warning: Because of the `CASCADE` other constraints are also dropped... You will have to re-create those too! (see DBFIDDLE from more info)

Then you als need to add the field `SpellID` to the table `Plattform`:

```
-- add field SpellID
ALTER TABLE plattform ADD COLUMN spellID INTEGER;
```

After that you can re-create the primary key of table `Plattform`:

```
-- add Primary KEY
ALTER TABLE plattform ADD PRIMARY KEY(plattformID, spellID);
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/M1jrGD3o)

Answer (score 0):

One game can be published on many platforms, and one platform can host many games. You need a **many-to-many relationship** between games and platforms in your relational model. See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Could look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE företag (
  företagid integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY  -- !
, företag text
, högk text
);

CREATE TABLE spel (
  spelid integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY  -- !
, företagid integer REFERENCES företag  -- !
, spel text  -- !
, genre text
, år date
, åldergräns integer  -- ?!
);

CREATE TABLE plattform (
  plattformid text PRIMARY KEY  -- !! natural key?
, plattform text
  -- more?
);
```

Above modifications are minor fixes and other suggestions.
Here comes the magic (the implementation of the m:n relationship):

```
CREATE TABLE spel_plattform (
  spelid integer REFERENCES spel
, plattformid text REFERENCES plattform
  -- more?
, PRIMARY KEY (spelid, plattformid)
);
```

Sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO företag (företagid, företag, högk) VALUES
  (1, 'Capcom', 'Japan')
, (2, 'From', 'Japan')
;

INSERT INTO spel (spelid, företagid, spel, genre, år, åldergräns) VALUES
  (1, 1, 'Zelda'     , 'Äventyr', '2015-10-12',  7)
, (2, 2, 'Bloodborne', 'A-RPG'  , '2017-09-09', 18)
, (3, 2, 'Elden Ring', 'A-RPG'  , '2022-01-01', 18)
;

INSERT INTO plattform (plattformid, plattform) VALUES
  ('NES', 'Nintendo Entertainment System')
, ('PS4', 'PlayStation 4')
;

INSERT INTO spel_plattform (spelid, plattformid) VALUES
  (1, 'NES')
, (1, 'PS4')
, (2, 'NES')
, (2, 'PS4')
, (3, 'PS4')
;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/raQ3Jb4l)